# Error 'unknown browser query' when building dotnet vuejs template

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, webpack, vuejs2

I installed the ASP.NET Core Vue.js 2 on a Windows 10 machine. When running the npm install command I am getting the following  error

> BrowserslistError: Unknown browser query `basedir=$(dirname "$(echo
>   "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")`
>       at error (C:\Repos\StudentSignPocNet\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:37:11)
>       at C:\Repos\StudentSignPocNet\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:222:9
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at browserslist (C:\Repos\StudentSignPocNet\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:196:13)
>       at cleanBrowsersList (C:\Repos\StudentSignPocNet\node_modules\caniuse-api\dist\utils.js:56:59)
>       at setBrowserScope (C:\Repos\StudentSignPocNet\node_modules\caniuse-api\dist\index.js:29:43)
>       at Object. (C:\Repos\StudentSignPocNet\node_modules\caniuse-api\dist\index.js:91:1)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:565:32)

I tried deleting the files browserslist and browserslist.cmd in the project  directory (solution that has helped others) but to no avail..

Error happens when webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js runs.

How can I resolve this error?
Let me know,
Bert-Jan

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, it was my bootstrap css import. Changed it from @import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"; to @import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';

Or try to downgrade bootstrap to 4.1.0, this also could resolve your problem.

Or try this version of bootstrap they fixed this error https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases/tag/v4.1.3